# Footer override with duplicate block name

Tags: magento, layout

I've got a pretty strange issue with module http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/visistat-connector-6644.html

It adds a block in `default` handle like this:

```xml
<default>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" template="sfcvisistat/tracking.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

effectively using the same name as standard footer.

This doesn't break any places but custom modules which get footer template from this definition thus having real footer removed

I've resolved the issue by changing name to something unique, however I'm curious if anyone has tips in debugging this issue, why this definition might be used out of `reference` context?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`before_body_end` would seem a more appropriate parent block if this is a remarketing script. As to why they would override the core footer is a question for the vendor.

---

**Edit: providing recommended best practice and context in response to OP comments:**

Ideally and in general in Magento theming and module development, any blocks added by the core team - especially structural blocks should not be removed or modified (without accounting for compatibility) by anyone other than the final implementor of a site (and then only with due deliberation). The reason for this is that other core code as well as third-party module code may expect the block instance to exist in layout *by the original name* and *with the exact same functionality*.

Now, the original post shows that the core block class for the footer is the same (`page/html_foot`), and the name is the same. The problems arise when the layout is processed, setting up the block hierarchy: the original (core) instance of the footer block is no longer accessible from the layout object (it's only accessible via its parent), and the new (custom) footer block instance will be the one referenced in any post-layout creation code.

Comment: agree about `before_body_end` note, but main concern here that it doesn't override footer on homepage for example, but does in custom module (which is using the same 1-column template)

Comment: Yep, there's no reason for this approach in a distributed module.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being unclear. The module mentioned in my question breaks footers on pages of other modules